# identify unique id from two variables

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe with two columns, P1 and P2. What I want to get is a new column called ID, the same values of P1 get the same ID, and the same values of P2 get the same ID.

```
P1  P2
a   1
a   1
a   2
b   2
c   3
c   4
```

So, I want to get the ID column as below:

```
P1  P2 ID
a   1  1
a   1  1
a   2  1
b   2  1
c   3  2
c   4  2
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: How exactly does `ID` depend on `P1` and `P2`?

Comment: What if `(a,4)` comes next?

Comment: (a, 4) has ID of 1 because the value sof P1 equal to a all have ID of 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get this is to treat your data as a graph.  The IDs are the connected components of the graph.

```
IDs = read.table(text="P1  P2
a   1
a   1
a   2
b   2
c   3
c   4",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(igraph)
G = graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(IDs), directed = FALSE)
IDs$ID = components(G)$membership[IDs$P1]
IDs
  P1 P2 ID
1  a  1  1
2  a  1  1
3  a  2  1
4  b  2  1
5  c  3  2
6  c  4  2
```

To help visualize this,

```
RES = bipartite_mapping(G)
V(G)$type = RES$type
LO = layout_as_bipartite(G)
plot(G, layout=LO)
```

[image: Graph View]

Comment: So does the 'components(G)$membership' mean the connected nodes are a unique unit?

Comment: Each component gets a unique (numerical) ID. `components(G)$membership` records which component each _vertex_ is in. Since you wanted to label the _links_, `components(G)$membership[IDs$P1]` assigns each link to the component of its first vertex.